# How do I turn a repetitive string into a function?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

At the moment I'm getting information from an API - I want to convert that information onto my site in a more user friendly way to see. The issue here is that the amount of the variable that I'm looking for keeps changing along with the answers in it, so I'm looking to create a function that will add a paragraph with a comma if there is another 'vehicle' - perhaps I've not explained it well, so I'll show an example.

Currently I have it like this:

```
document.getElementById("vehicle").innerHTML = data.vehicles[1]['classname']
document.getElementById("vehicle").innerHTML = data.vehicles[2]['classname']
document.getElementById("vehicle").innerHTML = data.vehicles[3]['classname']
```

Instead of writing that out a million times, I want to create a function that *adds* an element of the above for every time it sees it in the api, into my code.

For example I'd have

```
<p id="vehicle">...</p>
```

in my HTML, and if there was 1 vehicle with a classname Car in my api, it would replace `...` with `Car`. If there were 2 vehicles, one with classname `Car` and another `Boat`, it would replace `...` with `Car, Boat` - hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
content = data.vehicles.map(v => v.classname).join(", ");
document.getElementById("vehicle").textContent = content;
```

#### Addendum

1. `data.vehicles.map(v => v.classname)`
   Iterates through the `data.vehicles` array and takes only the class names.

   For example, if we have `[{classname: "Car"}, {classname: "Boat"}]`, then we will get `["Car", "Boat"]` back.
2. `.join(", ")`
   Joins the element by `", "`.

   For example, if we have `["Car", "Boat"]`, then we will get `"Car, Boat"` back.
3. `document.getElementById("vehicle").textContent`
   [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is the proper way of setting the text content of an element.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible for you to explain what's going on here? Hope I'm not asking for too much

Comment: @AntArni Added some explanations.

Comment: Using your code, I've tried to improvise a bit and replace certain results into more readable ones - for example, usually a result is "B_Quadbike_02" or something along the lines of that. I'm trying to replace every time it comes up with that into just "Quadbike". I've written some code but its not working, perhaps you can help:

var vehicleList = data.vehicles.map(v => v.classname);
        var vehicleListName = vehicleList.replace(/B_Quadbike_01/, 'Quadbike');
        
        content = vehicleList.join(", ");
        document.getElementById("vehicle").textContent = content;

Comment: @AntArni `vehicleList` is an array not a string, you can't use `.replace` on that. What you can do however is to map that across the array: `data.vehicles.map(v => v.classname).map(v => v.replace(/.+_(.+?)_.+/, "$1")).join(", ")`